# How to make sharedpreference from splash to main page

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to make my app look like facebook on the opening page where if the user has logged in the login page wont show anymore it goes directly from splash page to the home page. What's happening to my app is that from the splash the login page is still showing but with sharedpreference its loading immidietly to login the details that is stored in the shared. What I want to happen is the login page wont show anymore. Here is my code for better understanding. :)

## Splash

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences pref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Thread myThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                Intent in = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    myThread.start();
}
}
```

## Loginpage

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

Button btnLogin;
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
TextView tvRegister;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstname);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    tvRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);

    pref = getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);
    editor.commit();

    boolean hasLoggedIn = pref.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);

    if(hasLoggedIn){
        String username = pref.getString("username", "");
        String password = pref.getString("password", "");

        if (!username.equals("") && (!password.equals(""))) {
            postData.put("username", username);
            postData.put("password", password);
            authenticate(postData);
        }

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etUsername.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                editor = pref.edit();
                postData.put("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
                postData.put("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));
                editor.commit();
                authenticate(postData);
            }
        });
    }


    tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });


}

private void authenticate(final HashMap<String, String> postData) {
    PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this, postData,
            new AsyncResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    if (s.contains("renter")) {
                        // Login success, Save to prefs
                        editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.putString("username", postData.get("username"));
                        editor.putString("password", postData.get("password"));
                        editor.putString("userlevel", s);
                        editor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RenterTabs.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();

                    } else if (s.contains("owner")) {
                        // Login success, Save to prefs
                        editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.putString("username", postData.get("username"));
                        editor.putString("password", postData.get("password"));
                        editor.putString("userlevel", s);
                        editor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, OwnerTabs.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();
                    } else if (s.contains("driver")) {
                        editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.putString("username", postData.get("username"));
                        editor.putString("password", postData.get("password"));
                        editor.putString("userlevel", s);
                        editor.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Driver Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DriverTabs.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        finish();
                    } else if (s.contains("-1")) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong username or password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/carkila/authenticate.php");
}
}
```

btw, I'm using userlevel for the login. Thaanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    pref = getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);
    editor.commit();

    boolean hasLoggedIn = pref.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);

    if(hasLoggedIn){
        // that means no need to show your login page. so go to main activity
        Intent in = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);

    }else{
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          .................

          // others code goes here for login activity..
    }

}
```

you can apply same login in your splash screen... inside thread..

```
// check user login status from sharedpreference
if(loggedIn){
   // go to main activity
}else{
   // go to login activity
}
```